# Cannot find -lglut but freeglut3-dev is installed

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut

I'm trying to launch a test for opengl on my kubuntu 64b.
Opengl, glew and freeglut are installed but when I compile it says that glut is not found.

```
CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 52ms)

"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rxp/NetBeansProjects/Cpptest'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cpptest
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/rxp/NetBeansProjects/Cpptest'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -I../oglpg-8th-edition/include -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cpptest build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o -L../oglpg-8th-edition/lib -lGL -lGLEW -lGLU -lGLUT
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLUT
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/cpptest] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rxp/NetBeansProjects/Cpptest'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rxp/NetBeansProjects/Cpptest'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 358ms)
```

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You're using -lGLUT. Note that the libraries are case sensitive, so you need to use -lglut instead.
In build command, the libraries should be linked this way:

```
-lGL -lGLEW -lGLU -lglut
```